# Querying Tables in Batches Using Dapper Takes Too Long C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I have a C# code that pulls data from SQL using Dapper. I'm using `Offset` and `Fetch` in my query to pull data in batches to process on my code. When I run my query on SQL Server it returns the data pretty much instantly, but on my code it's quite slow.

Sample query

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.Id = a.Id
INNER JOIN table 3 c ON c.Id = a.Id
...
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET @OffSet ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Sample method

```
public async Task<List<MainObject> GetData(int offSet, int pageSize)
{
    var connection = //opens my connection
    
    return await connection.QueryAsync<MainObject, SubObject, MainObject>(
        myQuery,
        (a, b) =>
        {
            a.SubObject = b;
            return a;
        },
        splitOn: "Id"
    )
.Distinct()
.ToList;
}
```

On my main class I call the method

```
var offset = 0;
var pageSize = 1000;
var groupCount = (totalCount + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;

for(i = 1; i <= groupCount; i++)
{
    var data = await GetDataAsync(offSet, pageSize);
    
    //process the data 
    
    offset += pageSize;
}
```

Once I get the data back from SQL. The rest of my code runs fast until it pulls the next batch of data. It takes about 3 mins after pulling data gets triggered to get to the process data piece.
I'm pulling a lot of data and on average the groupCount would be around 20 or so.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to implement this and improve performance.